# SonarQube Analyse WARNING Journal flush operation (Does not End)

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Running SonarQube Server 4.5.6, Tested with Maven 3.0.5, Maven 3.3.9,

Using the command line like this:

```
mvn -B org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
```

Also tested different versions of the plugin (3.1.1 etc.).

I have already tested to enhance the memory options from 2 G to 22 G

```
-Xmx6g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

which did not help. Always the scan does not continue and getting this output:

```
00:23:08.815 15:36:06.724 WARN  - [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 14.164ms last 8 cycles average is 1.770ms
00:23:55.507 15:37:10.917 WARN  - [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3.696ms last 8 cycles average is 2.232ms
00:25:03.219 15:38:16.429 WARN  - [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3.493ms last 8 cycles average is 898ms
00:29:09.760 15:42:01.239 WARN  - [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3.513ms last 8 cycles average is 439ms
00:31:01.208 15:44:17.868 WARN  - [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 3.611ms last 8 cycles average is 451ms
00:34:22.694 15:47:30.643 WARN  - [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 22.496ms last 8 cycles average is 2.812ms
```

We have a large number of modules (ca. 600) in a single multi module build (Java / Tycho)...

Update: So the result keeps failure. Does a scan really take so much memory which is done module by module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after more investigation and research I found the following related issues:

- https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5995
- https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5878
- https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5551

Which means in other words I have to update the SonarQube version to a newer version.

Comment: What version did you upgrade to, and did it fix the problem? I'm using version 6.2 of SonarQube and I am getting those messages in my build too

Comment: I'm using version 6.7 and I'm getting the same messages